# Is there a way to access serverside ajax responses as temporary files?

Tags: javascript, json, browser, cross-browser, dom-events

In ancient times IE6 under MS windows XP at least let us access to ajax responses as files in the local filesystem under "temp" folder.

Is still there a way to access ajax responses as temporary files from modern browsers as well?

Comment: what's the end goal here? are you trying to debug an error, trace output, etc?  I think the answer is "no", but if you'll tell us what you're trying to do, there is probably a better way of going about it

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure modern browsers store ajax responses in (plain) temporary files.

If you want to view json responses in modern browsers, there are many tools like [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) for Firefox for example, it allows you to view the response from the server (Raw response or formatted json..)

Comment: +1 for using browser tools. Unless the OP has no access to a browser, this should be the way to do it.